# VB.NET - I don't Insert to database

Tags: database, vb.net, insert

I try LINQ VB.NET But it's work don't insert to database

this line ".CommandText = sqlAdd"

Msg Error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text

Public Class _1_1Invoice
    Dim db As New assetDataContext()
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim tr As SqlTransaction
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

Private Sub btSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click

        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want insert invoice?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            tr = Conn.BeginTransaction()

            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length)
            sb.Append("INSERT INTO tbl_AsInvoice (Poid)")
            sb.Append(" VALUES (@Poid)")
            Dim sqlAdd As String = sb.ToString()

            With cmd
                .CommandText = sqlAdd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Connection = Conn
                .Transaction = tr
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add("@Poid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPoid.Text.Trim()
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            tr.Commit()
            MessageBox.Show("Succesfull", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
```

Thanks you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` is nothing. You need to intialize it:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `cmd` therefore it is `Nothing` and its properties can't be accessed. You must create a new `SqlCommand` and assign it to `cmd`:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand()
With cmd
    ...
End With
```